# Bar Graphs with Matplotlib

Tags: python, csv, graph, matplotlib

I have a CSV file (Data.csv):

```
2012-01-01,0
2012-01-02,1
2012-01-03,8
2012-01-04,1
...etc
```

I am trying to make a bar graph, the dates on the x axis and the values on the y axis:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

def graph():
    date, value = np.loadtxt('Data.csv', delimiter=',', unpack=True,
        converters = {0: mdates.strpdate2num('%Y-%m-%d')})

    fig = plt.figure()

    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, axisbg='white')

    plt.plot_date(x=date, y=value, fmt='-')

    plt.title('Title')
    plt.ylabel('Value')
    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.show()

graph()
```

Unfortunately, this is a line graph.

Could someone please assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matplotlib documentation has a pretty good example: [barchart_demo.py](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html)

This should do it:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

bar1 = ax.bar(date, value)

plt.title('Title')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks - very useful. However this solution gets rid of the x-axis tick labels that came with `plt.plot_date(x=date, y=value, fmt='b')`. Is there any way they can be re-included?